# $5$ points are randomly chosen on the plane, what is the probability that the resulting conic is parabola, ellipse, hyperbola.

Tags: probability, conic-sections, curves

$5$ points are randomly chosen on the plane, what is the probability that the resulting conic is a parabola, an ellipse, or a hyperbola? By randomly chosen on the plane I mean chosen uniformly.

Comment: What is "the resulting conic"? How are you fitting a conic to the points?

Comment: there is no "uniform" probability distribution on the plane

Comment: Ok, take a large square of length $R$.

Comment: I suppose it suffices to consider just a square of unit length.

Comment: @user7530 It's known that 5 points uniquely define a conic.

Comment: Intuitively, the probability to get a parabola is 0 because it is a "transient state" between an ellipse and an hyperbola, as can be seen when you "slice" a cone by a plane (you have to take a plane parallel to a generatrix of the cone to get a parabola.

Comment: Besides that, you have to define a probability measure. It can be $dx_1dy_1dx_2dy_2 \cdots dx_5dy_5$ (where $(x_k;y_k)$ are the coordinates of the 5 points say on $[0,1]^5$, but this measure is not the best for manipulations. You can also take $dadbdcddde$ if the equation of the conic (not passing through the origin) is  $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+1=0$

Comment: Well for points I am implying the first, but that is also an interesting question.

Comment: Five point *in general position* determine a unique conic. If any three points are colinear, the conic is degenerate and might not be unique.

Comment: But the odds of them being colinear is zero.

Comment: Loosely speaking, an ellipse is associated with a positive determinant, a hyperbola with a negative determinant and a parabola with a zero determinant, hence for any reasonable definition of the actual probability space I would expect such probabilities to be close to $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0$.

Comment: But of course, one needs to give a clear definition of the probability space, otherwise the expression *random conic* is meaningless, just like the expressions *random real number* or *random point in the Euclidean plane*.

Comment: What's wrong with what I said, take 10 random reals from $0$ to $1$. Yeah, I expect it to be $50/50$ as well but I mean to use the determinant argument you somehow need to be able to find the determinant based off of $5$ points, certainly doable but not easy, and that's just the easy part. As far as I know, random real has been defined pretty well, its central to probability theory.

Comment: As comics are invariant to affine transformations we can fix 3 of the points say at $(0,0)$,$(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ and let the 2 remaining span the rest of the plane.